# Phase shifts introduced by a beam splitter

Tags: optics, photons, reflection, polarization

I am studying [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.02749) paper about the automatic generation of quantum experiments. The algorithm they are using is based on a series of symbolic transformations that are used to simulate the effects of different optic elements on a photon state and I can't understand how they came up with these transformations.

In particular they define (page 6) the action of a beam splitter on a photon as

$$\begin{cases}
\lvert H \rangle_a\rightarrow \lvert H \rangle_b-i\lvert H\rangle_a\\
\lvert H \rangle_b\rightarrow \lvert H \rangle_a-i\lvert H\rangle_b\\
\lvert V \rangle_a\rightarrow \lvert V \rangle_b+i\lvert V\rangle_a\\
\lvert V \rangle_b\rightarrow \lvert V \rangle_a+i\lvert V\rangle_b
\end{cases}
$$

where $a$ and $b$ represent the two optic paths that the photons can take, and the path changes name when it's *transmitted* while stays the same when it's *reflected*. From this transformation we see that the horizontal and vertical reflected photons have respectively a $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$ phase shifts with respect to the transmitted photons.

Now, I know from Fresnel's equations for a dielectric (negligible extinction coefficient $\kappa$) that the phase shift upon reflection can change (for small enough incidence angles) for the horizontal and vertical component of a photon, and the vertically polarized photon gains a $+\pi$ phase shift with respect to the horizontally polarized photon, but this doesn't match the beam splitter transformation they give in this paper.

Is it because at the same time the reflected photons (both vertical and horizontal) gain a phase shift of $\frac{\pi}{2}$ with respect to the transmitted photons? Why is it so?